# select a button using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

how to select login button using selenium web driver

```
<li id="buttons" class="greetings_fmt">
    <a href="#">
       <div class="user_btn log_in_icon">LOG IN</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
       <div class="user_btn sign_up_icon">SIGN UP</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

tried with this code but not working

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("buttons"));
      List<WebElement> ele1 = ele.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
      for(WebElement e : ele1){         
         e.click()

      }
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'LOG IN')]")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following xpath for user case:

Xpath=`//*[contains(text(),'LOG IN')]`

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks what you are trying to automate is incomplete.Login is not a button. It is a link. Clicking on this link will take you nowhere as **href="#"**.

Comment: when i tried am getting 'unknown error: Element <a href="#">...</a> is not clickable at point '